# Android Toolbar gets hidden and shown on RecycleView scroll

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, ontouchlistener

I have implemented the custom **Toolbar** and it is working good, all i wanted was when i **tap anywhere** on screen the toolbar gets **hidden** and on again tapping it gets **shown** and i achieved it by following code. But the only problem now is that if i am **scrolling my recycleView**, the toolbar takes it as touch and again gets hidden and shown on scroll also, i dont want it to happen, please help.

> I am using Android Studio
>   And also RecycleView + FrameLayout in it

```
 mrecyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (getSupportActionBar().isShowing()) {
                        getSupportActionBar().hide();
                    } else {
                        getSupportActionBar().show();
                    }
                    return true;
                } else return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: did you try attaching touch listener to your root view instead of recycler view?

Comment: @MohammedJunaid you mean the Frame layout which is used above recyclerView sir ?

Comment: yess. The root view of your fragment/activity.

Comment: @MohammedJunaid yes sir i tried to attach it but an error of Non-static method 'setOnTouchListener(android.view.View.OnTouchListener)' cannot be referenced from a static context , is comming on OnTouchListener

Comment: does your framelayout have id?

Comment: @MohammedJunaid yes sir, and i have tried findViewById and later on attached it to frame layout and on that frame layout i have attached onTouch listener but then the toolbar which was getting touches is not getting any touches, it does not matter how many touches i do, nothing happens.

Comment: Add a scrollListener and/or set a fling listener on your recyclerview and hide/show your toolbar the way you want.

Comment: @MohammedJunaid but sir i want to show and hide the toolbar on touch cant it be achieved like many applications, and with scrollListener the toolbar will hide only when scrolled, but what if a user wants to use the toolbar in between, i mean he have to scroll again.

Comment: Use the scroll/fling listener together with touch listener and set show toolbar inside scroll/fling listener.

Comment: @MohammedJunaid i am not getting it sir, can you please help me by giving an example or edit the above code please.

Answer (score 0):

in your Activity:

```
mrecyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (getSupportActionBar().isShowing()) {
                        getSupportActionBar().hide();
                    } else {
                        getSupportActionBar().show();
                    }
                    return true;
                } else return false;
            }
        });
```

after above touch listener add this

```
mrecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                getSupportActionBar().show();
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            }
        });
```

and do the same for setOnFlingListener after this.

Comment: what values i should give in onFling is it like below code

  mrecyclerView.setOnFlingListener(new RecyclerView.OnFlingListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onFling(int velocityX, int velocityY) {
                getSupportActionBar().show();
                return false;
            }
        });

Comment: yeap but return true.

Comment: no sir it did not help me :( , same problem is coming if i scroll the recyclerView it is making toolbar hide and visable on every touch. i want to make my toolbar stay hidden and only be shown on touch